# Analytic continuation of a series involving $\zeta(s)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, riemann-zeta, analytic-continuation

**Context:**

In this [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.facm/1317045228), Juan Arias de Reyna introduces on p12 the following equation for a new power series coefficient:

$$A_m = \lambda_m + \frac{\gamma + \log(4\pi)}{2}-\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=2}^{m}(-1)^j{m \choose j} \left(1-\frac{1}{2^j}\right)\zeta(j) \qquad m \in \mathbb{N} \tag{1}$$

Let's multiply (1) by $m$, isolate the last three terms and continue these to $s \in \mathbb{C}$. This gives:

$$f1(s) =s\cdot\frac{\gamma + \log(4\pi)}{2}-1- \sum_{j=2}^{\infty}(-1)^j{s \choose j} \left(1-\frac{1}{2^j}\right)\zeta(j) \qquad s \in \mathbb{C}, \quad \Re(s) > 0 \tag{2}$$

I've found ways to analytically continue both $A_m$ and $\lambda_m$ ([= Keiper/Li coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%27s_criterion)) into entire functions and this provided data to assess what the analytic continuation of (2) would look like. After some experiments, I managed to numerically derive the following simple function that appears entire:

$$f2(s) = s\cdot\frac{\gamma + \log(\pi)}{2}-\sum_{j=2}^{\infty}{-s \choose j} \frac{\zeta(j)}{2^j} \qquad s \in \mathbb{C}\tag{3}$$

**Question:**

Is there a way to prove that the entire function (3) is indeed the full analytic continuation of (2) ?

P.S.

A brief inspection of (3) showed it has at least two real zeros and also a couple of complex zeros, but all with $\Re(s)$ negative.

Comment: No idea what you mean with 'Keiper/Li constant'

Comment: Good catch. I changed the wording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\Re(s)>1$

$$\sum_{j=2}^{\infty}(-1)^j{s \choose j} \left(1-\frac{1}{2^j}\right)\zeta(j)=(1+(-1))^s-1+ s -\sum_{j=2}^{\infty}(-1)^j{s \choose j} \frac{1}{2^j}\zeta(j) $$
$$-1+ s -\sum_{j=2}^{\infty}(-1)^j{s \choose j} \frac{1}{2^j}\zeta(j) $$
The latter is entire as $\frac{1}{2^j}\zeta(j) $ has exponential decay and locally $${s \choose j}= \prod_{m=1}^j (\frac{s+1-m}{m})=O(e^{|s| \sum_{m\le j}1/m})= O(e^{|s|\log j})$$
which means local uniform convergence and analyticity.

Comment: Thans again. You make it look so easy...